# How to display data from a CloudFirestore sub-collection

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, collections, google-cloud-firestore

I have a database created in CloudFirestore like so:

Collection 'users'
Document 'uid' (uid is the uid that gives you the authentication of
firebase to each user)
Collection 'user information'.

What I want to know is what is the method to obtain and display the data of the collection 'user information' in a list that I have in a sccafold. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdXzS.png) is the structure of my database

Comment: Where’s your code? The one you tried and that’s not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My database structure

This is the code to call a subcollection into a document with name is equal to uid register.

Stream UserData(){[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWyYG.png)
    return Firestore.instance.collection('usuarios').document(uid).collection('informacionusuario').snapshots();
  }

Answer (score 0):

```
_firecloud.collection("coll-name").doc("doc-name").collection("sub-collection").get()
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25735054)